# Как сделать так чтобы слайд был на всю ширину, а иконки вправо и влево были поверх слайда, а не сбоку, скрипты оставил на описании фото

Tags: css, html5, slider

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel__photos').slick({
    infinite: true,
    speed: 1000,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    fade: false,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><img src="../src/icons/leftreal.svg"></button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><img src="../src/icons/rightreal.svg"></button>'
  });
});
```

Comment: при помощи CSS.